# Incrementing a Counter one item at a time in Python without using update

Tags: python, collections

I'm writing something in Python that involves using the `Counter` class in exactly the way the name implies: counting items one by one. Every time I want to count something I make a single element list out of it to feed to `Counter.update`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
c.update(["foo"])  # Works, but do I really need to create a list every time I want to do this?
```

Is this the right way to do it? Creating the list feels awkward. I've been looking for something like this:

```
c.add("bar")  # Method doesn't exist
```

Creating my own Counter subclass seems pretty painless, but it's nicer to deal with the built-in classes as designed if possible, and I wonder if I'm missing something.

```
class MyCounter(Counter):
    def add(self, item):
        self.update([item])

c2 = MyCounter()
c2.add("bar")  # Now it works
```

Comment: `c["foo"] += 1` is how everyone else does it ;-)

Comment: a `collections.Counter` object *is a `dict`*